# Alternative to "-webkit-backface-visibility:hidden" to stop flicker

Tags: html, css, css-transitions

I've been using `-webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;` to stop css transitions from flickering, but as a consequence my `position: fixed;` is no longer fixed in FF or Safari (see fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/liguha/ssqksnv0/)

Any alternatives? Preferably without javascript to fix this.

Answer (score 2):

Fought with this several times.  Doing it in the "*, *:before, *:after" may be causing the issue.
Trying to get graphics acceleration on any and all elements probably would cause a bit of lag downstream too.  box-sizing normally a safe bet, as with margin/padding.

So whats getting animated?  Typically if you have a transform going on you'll want to add the preserve-3d, and perspective.  Least from a parent/child relation ship you'll want to manage better what layers you setting these values on.

General rule I've used -
Container around what I'm animating:

```
perspective: 800px;
```

What I'm animating:

```
backface-visiblity: hidden;
transform: translate3d(0,0,0);
transform-style: preserve-3d;
```

If I still have flicker issues, I will normally add transform: translateZ(0); to some sub elements I'm animating that are directly flickering.

Its definitely a irritating issue thats span for years now and unfortunately all the tricks/tips age and become depreciated.  Check out Google Chrome's console to check re-draws and make sure the whole page isn't re-drawn when you scroll.  Typical sign its time for a translateZ(0) on the content of whats animating.

Good luck